# let div elements 'float' on page

Tags: html, css, css-float, positioning

I have a page (generated by php) which is filled with div elements. All the div's have random margins, random size and random color. There are 30 of them.

I want these div's to fill the page themselves, so there is the fewest whitespace possible, this way they form a kind of puzzle.

This is my html:

```
<div class="board"><!--30 divs with random styles and class="card--></div>
```

and CSS:

```
div.card {
    float: left;
}
div.board {
   display: ;
}
```

what do I have to fill in in the display property? I tried a lot and `run-in` suits the best but it still does not create a 'puzzle' effect.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered using masonry? http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With pure HTML and CSS you could try making all divs:

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Except I imagine with divs varying in size you'll still get whitespace between them.

For a true tiled layout with minimal whitespace you may want to consider [**MASONRY**](http://masonry.desandro.com/).